# Make sure to register a handler via on<AppStarted>((event, emit) {...})

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Este es el error que me salta todo el rato. Es con la libreria de bloc, ya no se que hacer jeje.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following StateError was thrown attaching to the render tree:
Bad state: add(AppStarted) was called without a registered event handler.
Make sure to register a handler via on<AppStarted>((event, emit) {...})
```

Ese error me salta en esta parte del código:

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {

  AuthenticationBloc? authenticationBloc;

  UserRepository get userRepository => widget.userRepository;

  @override
  void initState() {
    authenticationBloc = AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: userRepository);
    authenticationBloc!.add(AppStarted()); // En esta línea justo me pasa el error.
    super.initState();
  }
//etc
```

```
class AuthenticationBloc  extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  final  UserRepository userRepository;

  AuthenticationBloc({required this.userRepository}) : assert(userRepository != null), super(AuthenticationUninitialized());
```

```
abstract class AuthenticationEvent extends Equatable {
  AuthenticationEvent([List props = const []]) : super();
}

class AppStarted extends AuthenticationEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'AppStarted';

  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

Si necesitáis algo más de información me lo decís. Y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Léete la documentación de bloc y mira algún ejemplo de implementación. El fallo está en authentication bloc. Necesita llamar a una función para manejar los eventos entrantes y según veo, no lo has hecho.

Comment: No consigo sacar nada útil. Ya no se ni que hacer

Comment: Échale un ojo a la doc. No creo que de verdad la hayas mirado. De haberlo hecho, podrías solucionar el problema. No te ofendas, no es que no te quiera ayudar o menospreciar tu esfuerzo, pero se nota bastante que no sabes usar el package, por tanto, lo mejor es que aprender, a través de la documentación, con todos los ejemplos que esta provee: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts. Échale un buen ojo. Verás que es sencillo de implementar.